# How to migrate SoapUI test scripts into Postman

Tags: soapui, postman

I have all my test scripts implemented in SoapUI tool for both Soap and Rest APIS, now i am planning to migrate to PostMan. Is there any way by which i can convert my already written testscripts into Postman as hassle-free.

PS: I know the reverse is possible using a plugin which SoapUI supports.

Comment: This might help you: http://blog.getpostman.com/2016/04/27/importing-soapui-projects-into-postman/

Comment: Thanks for your reply @SivcanSingh .. It is exporting only API definition, but i want all of my test suites along with testcases to be migrated. Is there any plugin kind of a thing available..